# Removing extra newline in GitHub Markdown Unordered List

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I have the following code in a .md file that I'm using to create a GitHub page:

```
# Navigation
 - [Create a GitHub repository](#create-a-github-repository)
 - [Create a GitHub Pages site](create-a-github-pages-site)
 - [README file use and work portfolio content](readme-file-use-and-work-portfolio-content)
    - [Add text documentation](add-text-documentation)
    - [Insert images](insert-images)
 - [Additional documentation](additional-documentation)

 - [Create a GitHub repository](#create-a-github-repository)
 - [Create a GitHub Pages site](create-a-github-pages-site)
 - [README file use and work portfolio content](readme-file-use-and-work-portfolio-content)
     - [Add text documentation](add-text-documentation)
     - [Insert images](insert-images)
 - [Additional documentation](additional-documentation)
```

Note: I have it twice because I'm trying multiple ways to format this correctly.

For whatever reason, it keeps showing an extra space between the indented part of the list and the last item. I've included a link to the image here.

Any ideas why it's doing this? I'm using Jekyll and the Modernist theme to render the page. Thanks in advance.

[Screenshot of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UB1L.png)

[Link to the actual website](https://emiliebarnard.github.io/github-page-guide/)

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with the Modernist theme. Fixed it by creating a new file named **assets/css/style.scss** with the following:

```
---
---

@import "{{ site.theme }}";

ul{ margin: 0px !important;}
```